# The most compact and neat way about overriding a function in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, overriding

I am trying to write a class, for text manipulation. The idea is class will support basic text preprocessing, but if someone wants to write a very complex preprocessing function, they should be able to use the base class and override it. I tried the following way, even though I can somehow make it to work, I don't think that is the correct way to do it.

```
class TextPreprocessor:
    def __init__(self, corpus):
        """Text Preprocessor base class.

            corpus: a list of sentences

        """
        self.corpus      = corpus
        self.word_tokens = [self.preprocess(sentence) for sentence in corpus]

    def preprocess(self,sentence):
        """
        strip each sentence , lowercase it and split by space # sentence.strip().lower().split()

        """

        return sentence.strip().lower().split()

    def preprocess_transform(self,sentence):

        return self.preprocess(sentence)
```

Now, if I want to write a new preprocessing function, which is the best way to do it. I tried following,

```
class SubPreprocess(TextPreprocessor):
    def __init__(self, corpus):
        #### dummy preprocess function
        def preprocess(self, sentence):
            return sentence.strip().split() + ['HELLOOOOOOOOOOLLLL']
        super.__init__(corpus)
```

It is not working. What I want basically, is the preprocess function ( modified ), should be able to override the one in base class `TextPreprocessor`, so that when that `__init__` is called, `self.word_tokens`, should be based on the new preprocessing function

Comment: Why are you newtingthe function in `__init__`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will do:

```
class SubPreprocess(TextPreprocessor):
    def preprocess(self, sentence):
        return sentence.strip().split() + ['HELLOOOOOOOOOOLLLL']
```

If you now call the constructor of `SubPreprocess`, the new `preprocess` method will be used:

```
proc = SubPreprocess(some_corpus)  
# looks up any methods in the mro of SubPreprocess
```

Comment: interesting, I didn't realise that doing it like this also inherits the __init__ function

Comment: @Karl Otherwise, inheritence would be rather useless. You only override the methods that need to change. When these are called by other methods, the [mro](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order) of `self.__class__` determines the lookup order.

Comment: I did the same thing, and it didn't work. But, now when I looked at my code, I realized that, after creating ```SubPreprocess``` class, I was calling ```TextPreprocessor``` , unknowingly. This is the best way. Thanks. Upvoted. :-)

Comment: @Karl - This is preferred because, someone who is interested in using the base class, but only wants to change ```preprocess``` function, he/she should be kept away from additional complexities. That's all.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, yeah that's clear. Somehow it just never occurred to me that this applies to `__init__` as well. In almost every example I saw for how inheritance was handled in Python, the subclass always had its own constructor and the superclass was explicitly called from there. Nice to learn something neat on a Friday afternoon

Answer (score 2):

```
class SubPreprocess(TextPreprocessor):
    def __init__(self, corpus):
        #this is how you initialise the superclass
        super(SubPreprocess, self).__init__(corpus)

    # the overridden function should be within the scope of the class, not under the initializer
    def preprocess(self, sentence):
        return sentence.strip().split() + ['HELLOOOOOOOOOOLLLL']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject behavior, just use a function:

```
class TheAlgorithm:
  def __init__(self, preprocess):
     self.preprocess = preprocess
  def process(self, corpus):
     after_a = self.part_a(corpus)
     preprocessed = self.preprocess(after_a)
     return self.part_b(preprocessed)
```

Use very simply:

```
p = TheAlgorithm(lambda c: c.strip().split() + 'helllol')
p.process('the corpus')
```

Actually, if all your class does is store some functions, you can go full-functional programming:

```
def processor(preprocess):
   def algorithm(corpus):
      return part_b( preprocess(corpus) )

p = processor(lambda c: "-".join(c.split(",")))
assert "a-b-c" == p("a,b,c")
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the  : super.**init**(corpus)
to super().**init**(corpus)